# Server error :Uploads directory not writable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and while uploading a file I get this error "Server error :Uploads directory not writable".

I have tried setting the seucrity to everyone for all folders from wp-content but still getting the error.

I am not able to make out what else can be the problem.

Can anyone guide me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: I can directly access the server.

Comment: "I have tried setting the seucrity to everyone for all folders" how are the permissions set up?

Comment: By going to each folder from wp-content and further all folders and then from properties->security->everyone

Comment: Everyone what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

There are two major causes to such problem:

1. Insufficient permissions, in order Wordpress to write contents in a folder, this folder should have *at least 0x755* permission set.
2. Insufficient disk space, most probably you ran out of free space on your server.

Other not so common cause is some sort of web server misconfiguration or hardware failure.

Comment: Changing the chmod working not on every host. Mostly the PHP process running on the webserver user. If the files uploaded by FTP and the FTP has an another user, it works only with chmod 0766 (Write access to all users). Otherwise a chown to the webserver-user will works.

Comment: Hi bodi0 there is no problem of the disk space there is 8gb free space.Can you please tell how to exactly set the permission set for the folder because I have given the security permission for the folder to "Everyone".

Comment: First, I need to know how do you access your server, via FTP client like Filezilla, by SSH, or you use some sort of web configuration panel...

Comment: As it is an internal server I can directly access the server via remote connection.

Comment: Use `chmod` command from linux shell (bash), like this: `chmod 0755 /full/path/to/your/upload/folder`